# Variable Only Echoes Out for Older Login IDs

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a MySQL table called "login" with the structure below.  The code beneath the table structure uses data pulled from the table "login."

For certain loginids that were created about two months ago, the code echoes out the variable "website" fine, no problem.  For loginids that I have created recently, the code does not echo out the variable "website."  I have even tried giving a newer and olders loginid the exact same value for "website," and the problems persists.
Any idea why is happening?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
`login` (
  `loginid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `actcode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `disabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `activated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `points` bigint(9) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`loginid`)
)
```

Edit: Here is the complete query:

```
  $sqlStrw = "SELECT l.username, l.loginid, l.website, c.loginid, c.commentid, c.submissionid, c.comment, c.datecommented, l.created, count(c.commentid) countComments
               FROM comment AS c
         INNER JOIN login AS l
                 ON c.loginid = l.loginid
              WHERE l.username = '$profile'";


  $resultw = mysql_query($sqlStrw);

$arrw = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrecw\">";
while ($roww = mysql_fetch_array($resultw)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename5">Website: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.'.$roww["website"].'" TARGET="_blank">'.$roww["website"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: you need to provide more of the code, how is $roww retrieved? Also have you considered the website field might be empty which is why it doesnt show?

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't show when there is data in the table.

Comment: Okay, I added the complete query.

Comment: Quick guess: there are no comments for those users/logins? Quick guess 2: what happens if you force `htmlspecialchars($roww["website"], ENT_QUOTES)` around the website echo, instead of just dumping it raw?

Comment: Wrikken, thanks, you answered the problem.  If the loginid has no comment, then the website is not echoed.  Thanks!  Now I can fix it.  Please post your observation in the form of an answer so that I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

The `inner join`  will only return rows from `login` which have a maching `loginid` in `comment`. You may want a ''right outer'' join here.